# Unable to show multiple figures in matplotlib using patchworklib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I am working on a project that involves matplotlib integrated with pyqt. I intend to combine several figures using [patchworklib](https://github.com/ponnhide/patchworklib), but I encountered an issue. Despite my efforts, only one figure appears in the GUI. Could you please assist me in identifying what might be causing this issue?

Below are the relevant sections of my code:

```py
import sys

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import patchworklib as pw

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Matplotlib in PyQt5 Example')
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # 创建 Matplotlib 的画布
        self.canvas = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)


class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        # fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        # fig = Figure()
        self.ax1 = pw.Brick()
        self.ax2 = pw.Brick()

        ax1 = self.plot(self.ax1)
        ax2 = self.bar(self.ax2)
        # Concatenate axes
        ax12 = ax1 | ax2
        fig = ax12.savefig()
        super().__init__(fig)
        self.setParent(parent)
        self.draw()

    def plot(self, ax_):
        x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        y = [10, 20, 25, 30, 35]
        ax_.plot(x, y)
        ax_.set_title('Matplotlib Plot in PyQt5')
        ax_.set_xlabel('X Label')
        ax_.set_ylabel('Y Label')
        return ax_

    def bar(self, ax_):
        categories = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
        values = [7, 10, 15, 5, 9]
        ax_.bar(categories, values, color='skyblue')
        ax_.set_title('Matplotlib Bar Chart in PyQt5')
        ax_.set_xlabel('Categories')
        ax_.set_ylabel('Values')
        return ax_


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]